# Does geopandas to_crs() method access the internet for ESRI Information?

Tags: geopandas, shapely, pyproj, fiona

This is a general inquiry regarding the utility of the python geopandas module and attempting to transform a geodataframe to a new coordinate reference system (crs). When a user initializes the geopandas to_crs() method to transform the geodataframe for a given string, such as "WGS84", does it attempt to access the internet to find the crs information for that given string? If so, then what website does geopandas refer to when downloading the crs information for a given user string within the to_crs() method?

The reason why I am asking this particular question is because certain supercomputers have firewalls up to block internet connections for given python packages that attempt to access internet pathways. When I executed the geopandas to_crs() method on a certain supercomputer, the method was just stuck and wouldn't render, which usually means that the something was attempting to access an internet connection and it remained hanging due to a firewall. Thanks for the time and assistance with this question.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't connect to the internet. It uses pyproj, which wraps PROJ. PROJ has a SQLite database it uses to lookup the projection information.